# reprojection and write grib files

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, gdal-translate, grib-2

I'm working on GRIB file, In input, I have the file with data from 0 to 360°.

As gdalwarp does not write GRIB file (only gdal_translate), I use gdal warp to projct data from [0,360] & [-90;90] to [-180,180] & [-90;90] and I write a geotiff file.
Then I use gdal_translate to write a grib file from Geotiff. 
When I do a gdalinfo on my output from gdal I have a bounding box =[-180,180] & [-90;90] but when I display the output grib file the bounding box is box =[180,540] & [-90;90].

Here are the commands I used:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 -wo SOURCE_EXTRA=100  --config CENTER_LONG 0 -overwrite  -of GTiff input.GR2 output_temp.tiff
gdal_translate -of GRIB --config CENTER_LONG 0 -co "DATA_ENCODING=JPEG2000" output_temp.tiff  output.GR2
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try only including `--config CENTER_LONG 0` in gdalwarp (remove it from gdal_translate).  I work with these files all the time with a very similar workflow, and don't have that issue, but I only have the CENTER_LONG setting in my gdalwarp command.

Comment: Hello,thanks for your answer. I got the answer and it is due to gdal version. On gdal version before 2.3, grib file can't have negative longitude values. On this case, it will add 360° to longitude values. THe last qgis version is based on 2.2.3 gdal version and doest not manage grib file with negative values for longitude. Since May 2018 and the new gdal version, gdal manage it: (https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/511) . Regards, Antoine